# Regex to remove ;# in string after first occurance

Tags: regex, sharepoint

I need help in building a regex to help me remove ;# in a string and replace it with a , after the first occurrence. For the first occurrence of the the ;# I want to remove it and subsequent ;# I want to replace with a ,. An example of what I am looking for is below:

```
;#something@domain.com;#something2@domain2.com;#
```

needs to end up being:

```
something@domain.com,something2@domain.com
```

Comment: Replace ;# with , and then split by 1st ,

Comment: Try `(?!\;|\#)([^\@]+\@[^\;]+)`

Answer (score 0):

replace ";#" with "," and then trim the first and the end ","

```
string input = ";#something@domain.com;#something2@domain2.com;#";
string afterEdit = input.Replace(";#", ",").TrimStart(',').TrimEnd(',');
```